# Is it possible to open a website using framebusting in a browser window in an app?

Tags: browser

If a website uses framebusting is it possible to open it in a browser in an app? or does this conflict with each other? Would it matter on what mobile platform you try this?

Answer (score 0):

On any platform, whether you can open a web page should not essentially be affected by framebusting or by whether the browser is embedded in an app.

So far as I know, framebusting usually relies on Javascript. If your platform supports Javascript then the browser will initially load the URL you specified but then the framed part that has framebusting will force a load of it's unframed URL.

If your platform does not support Javascript, or has it turned off, it will load the original (framing) page and any framed content. If any part of that page depends on Javascript to insert some of it's content then you will not see the information correctly.

Some websites have the opposite - Javascript that reloads a navigational frame around a URL that is only intended to be seen in that context. Again this action is only affected by whether Javascript is supported and enabled.